# checked radio button by name in jquery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I checked a radio button by using the name instead of id in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox[name=someName]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

generally, attribute-based selectors take the form

[name op pattern]

(including the brackets) where `name` is the name of the attribute, `op` is a relational operator, and `pattern` is matched against the attribute's value.  see Attribute Filters [in the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)